# Pandas: Efficient way to do loops with groupby objects

Tags: python, group-by, pandas

I have a very large DataFrame and I would like to do some heavy group wise comparisons. As an example lets take the following sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['foo', 'bar'] * 3,
               'B': ['me', 'you', 'me'] * 2,
               'C': [5, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9]})
```

Now I would like to group by column A and efficiently loop through these groups and make row wise comparisons in the following way:

```
gb = df.groupby(['A'])

for k, gp in gb:
    for i in arange(len(gp['C'])):
        sum = 0
        for j in arange(len(gp['C'])):
            if (i != j):
                sum = sum + gp['C'].irow(j)
        print gp['C'].irow(i) - sum
```

Is there a possibility to do this operation more efficient and assign its results to a separate column in the Dataframe.

I would deeply appreciate your help

Andy

Answer (score 3):

It seems a little strange to me, but IIUC, your output is given by

```
df["weird_C"] = 2*df["C"] - df.groupby("A")["C"].transform(np.sum)
```

For example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['foo', 'bar'] * 3,
               'B': ['me', 'you', 'me'] * 2,
               'C': [5, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9]})
>>> df
     A    B  C
0  foo   me  5
1  bar  you  2
2  foo   me  3
3  bar   me  4
4  foo  you  6
5  bar   me  9
>>> df["weird_C"] = 2*df["C"] - df.groupby("A")["C"].transform(np.sum)
>>> df
     A    B  C  weird_C
0  foo   me  5       -4
1  bar  you  2      -11
2  foo   me  3       -8
3  bar   me  4       -7
4  foo  you  6       -2
5  bar   me  9        3
```

---

Basically, things work better in `pandas` the more you can do at once, in fast vectorized C.  In this case, rather than looping over the group members, we can take the sum at once and then subtract off the extra bits we added:

```
>>> df.groupby("A")["C"].sum()
A
bar    15
foo    14
Name: C, dtype: int64
```

Better still, we can use `transform` so that broadcasting will give us a Series of the group sums:

```
>>> df.groupby("A")["C"].transform(np.sum)
0    14
1    15
2    14
3    15
4    14
5    15
Name: C, dtype: int64
```

and then since we have the total of the group and we really want the difference between each value and the others, we can think of "x - rest" as "x + x - x - rest", or "x + x - (total)", or "2*x - total":

```
>>> 2*df["C"] - df.groupby("A")["C"].transform(np.sum)
0    -4
1   -11
2    -8
3    -7
4    -2
5     3
Name: C, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Hi DSM, thank you very much for your help. Sorry for the confusion. The calculation way just an example. Actually there are objects in the rows with which I need to do calculations. What would you recommend for this special case?